# Hive date conversion

Tags: sql, hive

I intended to extend certain records in a table by adding `366 days` to its date keys:

`to_date(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20150101' ,'yyyyMMdd'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), 366))` as new_date

> > 2016-01-01

But how to convert this value back to format of original key i.e. `20160101` ?

Comment: You have already provided your own answer! Use the same format you have for the input date 'yyyyMMdd'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your requested date is 2016-01-01 it seems you want to add 365 days and not 366.

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(
           '20150101','yyyyMMdd')),365),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd');
```

---

Demo

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(
    >            '20150101','yyyyMMdd')),365),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'yyyyMMdd');
OK
20160101
```

Answer (score 0):

**`date_add`** gives you a date type as output.
As you have already used `from_unixtime` and `unix_timestamp`, I'll assume that you are already aware of their functionalities.
In Hive/Impala, there's no native `DATE_FORMAT` function like MySQL/MariaDB, so you'll have to convert the output of your **`date_add`** to **`unix_timestamp`** and then use **`from_unixtime`** on the output to achieve the desired format.

Something along the lines of:

```
select 
   from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(
   date_add(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('20150101' ,'yyyyMMdd')), 365)), 
   'yyyyMMdd');
```

Comment: could you please add an explanation what your code does, as well as some linebreaks so it is actually readable?